Building or compiling bazel for RISC-V architecture
I have running Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat) on HiFive Unmatched board. I am trying to either install bazel compiler or compile it from sources. It is either not available in apt-repositories for which I know of, or compiling bazel eats too much RAM and Java heap space.
Did anyone else try to get bazel compiler on RISC-V based Linux computer?

Maybe the easiest thing here is to use cross-compilation. You can try https://github.com/hexdae/toolchains_riscv_gnu to cross-compile your code to RISC-V. This will get you around RAM and Java heap space on your host machine of you use a decent developer machine.
